# How to block port 80 in Google Flex App Engine Environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to block port 80 in Google Flexible AppEngine

For example, when I run:

```
sudo nmap -O <project-id>.appspot.com
```

It shows:

Nmap scan report for .appspot.com

```
**PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https**
```

Here it shows port 80 is open.

I want to block/close port 80 in Flexible AppEngine. How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried creating a firewall rule? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/creating-firewalls

Comment: If your goal is to prevent users from using HTTP and to support HTTPS only, create a redirect in your application that sends the user to your HTTPS endpoint.